# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tortoise.inference' for Tortoise-tts-Fast

Tags: pip

I am trying to install [tortoise-tts-fast web GUI](https://github.com/152334H/tortoise-tts-fast) but I keep getting this error. This is after I run `**streamlit run scripts/app.py**`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tortoise.inference' Traceback: File "D:\Users\Miner Rebirth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script exec(code, module.__dict__) File "C:\Users\Miner Rebirth\tortoise-tts-fast\tortoise-tts-fast\scripts\app.py", line 11, in <module> from tortoise.inference import (`

How do I resolve this?

Here is the medium tutorial: https://medium.com/@martin-thissen/5x-faster-voice-cloning-tortoise-tts-fast-tutorial-5b8c1d4de975

And video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8i4T5v1Fl_M&ab_channel=MartinThissen

When I run streamlit run scripts/app.py` I get the following error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tortoise.inference' Traceback: File "D:\Users\Miner Rebirth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script exec(code, module.__dict__) File "C:\Users\Miner Rebirth\tortoise-tts-fast\tortoise-tts-fast\scripts\app.py", line 11, in <module> from tortoise.inference import (`

**UPDATE:** I ran pip install . in the directory and now I get this error when running `streamlit run scripts/app.py`:

```
AssertionError
Traceback:
File "D:\Users\Miner Rebirth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 552, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\Miner Rebirth\tortoise-tts-fast\scripts\app.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tortoise.api import MODELS_DIR
File "D:\Users\Miner Rebirth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tortoise\api.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tortoise.models.vocoder import VocConf
File "D:\Users\Miner Rebirth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tortoise\models\vocoder.py", line 406, in <module>
    assert STATIC_DIR.is_dir()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Edit D:\Users\Miner Rebirth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tortoise\models\vocoder.py
Search for "static" and change:

```
STATIC_DIR = Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent/'static'
```

to...

```
STATIC_DIR = Path("C:\Users\Miner Rebirth\tortoise-tts-fast\static")
```